# how to link css/js/whatever with random name to html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I link any local css/js file from a certain folder to my html? I mean not specifying the exact names of those files?

Comment: so you have mutliple js and css files or a single js or css which has a random name?

Comment: Do you mean without specifying their absolute paths?

Comment: With HTML alone you can't.

Comment: are you trying implementing theming or something else?

Comment: You would need to insert the links server-side before sending the page to the browser

Comment: I mean I have a folder where the css (or js) files will be stored in. But I want to link any css file to my html from that folder, whatever it's name is. It could be new_style.css or red_theme.css or whatever. I just want my html to grab css with any name from the folder.

Comment: Yes, it is clear what your goal is. It's still impossible without a preprocessor.